# Dynamic GetElementById - it's null

Tags: javascript, dynamic, getelementbyid

hey i create an Element with id and an eventListener. so when i click a link i  want to get the id.

But i don't have Control of this created Element. "cannot set property ... of null".

```
function insertLink(text,link,window,underline)
{

    var doc = document.getElementById("iframe_editor").contentWindow.document;      
    var sel = doc.getSelection();
    var count = parseInt(document.getElementById("counter").value);
    if (sel.rangeCount > 0)
    {
        count ++;
        document.getElementById("counter").value = count;
        var range= sel.getRangeAt(0);

        myParent=document.getElementById("iframe_editor").contentWindow.document.body;
        alink=document.createElement("a");

        var text = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("linktext").value);

        alink.href = document.getElementById("linkhref").value;
        alink.id = "testid"+count;

        alink.appendChild(text);    
        myParent.appendChild(alink);
        range.insertNode(alink);
        alink.addEventListener( 'click', function(){
            loadElement(count.toString());
        },count );
    }
}

function loadElement(t)
{
    alert(t);
    document.getElementById("testid"+t).innerHTML = "<a href = ''>Test</a>";
}
```

When i check the variable t in loadElement i get back the right number. But i cannot Change this element with innerhtml.

why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you inserted does not exist in your actual web page, but inside your iframe. So, you have to access it from the iframe:

```
document.getElementById("iframe_editor").contentWindow.document.getElementById("testid"+t).innerHTML = "<a href = ''>Test</a>";
```